# Responsive Image on ionic Tab bar

Tags: angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic for my project and I got a problem with Tab bar.I would love to know  How to set images on ionic tab bar instead of icons So that the images get re-sized based on the various device size .

Comment: you can also resize icons to any size. Just use a css media query and then use ng-class to resize the icons by setting a larger/smaller font-size to them. Also since the icons are all css they are very lightweight and you wont have to worry about file size in your app.

Comment: Thanks @Jess for the quick reply . Though I don't want to use any default css icons and text in the tab bar. I have 5 tabs in the footer of my screen and i have included background images to them instead of the icons . and now i want those images to be resized  as par the screen size of the device. the images looks good in some devices but when the width of the screen gets increased, it got screwed . please help.

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: div {
    background: url(img_flwr.gif);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
Also what size are the images you are using?

Comment: Thanks @JessPatton Ok I tried that but it didn't work as my expectation. Let me put some Code here I am using .

Answer (score 0):

My tabs.html look like this ... iys pretty symple

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-only tabs-color-active-positive">

 <!-- Profile Tab -->
<ion-tab title="profile" icon-off="profile" icon-on="profile" href="#/tab/profile">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- offer Tab -->

<ion-tab title="offers" icon-off="offers" icon-on="offers" href="#/tab/offers">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-offers"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>


<!-- inbox Tab -->
 <ion-tab title="inbox" icon-off="inbox" icon-on="inbox" href="#/tab/inbox">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-inbox"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- share Tab -->

 <ion-tab title="share" icon-off="share" icon-on="share" href="#/tab/share">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-share"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

 <!-- settings Tab -->

 <ion-tab title="settings" icon-off="settings" icon-on="settings"  href="#/tab/settings">
 <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


 </ion-tabs>
```

and the related css is

```
.tabs .tab-item .icon.profile {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('../img/profile.png');
 background-size:cover;
}


.tabs .tab-item .icon.offers {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('../img/offer.png');
 background-size:cover;
 }


.tabs .tab-item .icon.inbox {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('../img/inbox.png');
 background-size:cover;
}

.tabs .tab-item .icon.share {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('../img/share.png');
 background-size:cover;
}

.tabs .tab-item .icon.settings {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('../img/setting.png');
 background-size:cover;
}
```

The Width of the images are 126 pixel and height 107 pixel

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, tab items have a max-width set of 150px, if you increase that the images should be able to scale correctly, here is my code where i got it working even at very large width resolutions I also set the width on each tab item to 100%: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">

      </ion-content>
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-only tabs-color-active-positive">

 <!-- Profile Tab -->
<ion-tab title="profile" icon-off="profile" icon-on="profile" href="#/tab/profile">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- offer Tab -->

<ion-tab title="offers" icon-off="offers" icon-on="offers" href="#/tab/offers">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-offers"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>


<!-- inbox Tab -->
 <ion-tab title="inbox" icon-off="inbox" icon-on="inbox" href="#/tab/inbox">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-inbox"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- share Tab -->

 <ion-tab title="share" icon-off="share" icon-on="share" href="#/tab/share">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-share"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

 <!-- settings Tab -->

 <ion-tab title="settings" icon-off="settings" icon-on="settings"  href="#/tab/settings">
 <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


 </ion-tabs>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Styles here */
.tab-item{
  max-width: 300px;
}

.tabs .tab-item .icon.profile {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-1.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
}


.tabs .tab-item .icon.offers {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-7.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
 }


.tabs .tab-item .icon.inbox {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-2.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
}

.tabs .tab-item .icon.share {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-4.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
}

.tabs .tab-item .icon.settings {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-5.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jess ... It almost solve the problem . only two things .

Comment: Thank you @Jess ... It almost solve the problem .I have tested it on firefox and it looks good but I cant see any images in chrome . I will check it in mobile device at night and lets see. the images perfectly fitted by width but while increasing the screen size it gets a little out of focus by its width . how can I increase the default tab size ... may be that's how I can manage the problem.

Comment: so .tab-item class uses a flex box. has a max-width set(defualt to 150) if you keep haiving width issues you can just keep increasing the maxwidt or i think you can remove the max-width class altoghether and set the width of each tab to 100%, , and a height set 100% (height of tab bar is set by the .tabs class. the .tabs class has a height of 49px set. if you want the tabs to have more height simple change the height in the .tabs class